# Dataframes Not Merging properly. Getting an extra column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, jupyter-notebook

I want to join Dataframes with same column names into a single dataframe. When I press " df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, sort=False)", I get an extra column. Please help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b8dv.png)

[This is how I am Getting the Concatenated Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBd3x.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is `State` column has space in one DataFrame like  `State` or `State` , so after `concat` was not join with `State` column.

Solution is:

```
#test columns names
print (df1.columns)
print (df2.columns)

#remove trailing spaces
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.strip()
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.strip()
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not recognizing the "state" as the same field. I'd probably start by taking a look at the setup of the state field in each table to see why it thinks they're different. If you can find a different, format them to be the same and then try again.